# Transpiling Javascript to Javascript replacing objects and methods

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to convert a JS file containing an object myObject with method myMethod1() like this :

```
 myObject.myMethod1():
```

to another JS file with an object yourObject with method yourMethod() like this:

```
 yourObject.yourMethod2();
```

One of the possible ways would be writing a file manipulation program where one would replace occurrences using regex or simple text search by referring to some sample file, but this is too naive and I am eager to know if there are other possibilities. I am essentially writing a generic javascript library that produces the same interface for different libraries with each library having different methods but which internally implement the same functionality. For eg, if library A has an object A1 with method foo and library B has an object B1 with method bar , but foo and bar internally implement the same functionality, I am trying to create a solution wherein calling method meh on object S1 will call either A1.foo() or B1.bar() based on simple configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This could be very very difficult to achieve as

```
myObject.myMethod1()
```

is equivalent to

```
myObject['myMethod1']()
```

where the string 'myMethod1' could be the result of arbitrary expressions and variables, impossible to trace in practice.